# PyroCMS CKEditor: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing /

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, ckeditor, pyrocms

I'm using PyroCMS 2.x based on the Codeigniter framework. When I open the file editor in the admin backend (/admin/files), it is not working but redirects me to the start page. The file editor is based on CKEditor. I had the same issue earlier and fixed it but now it happened again and I can't find the solution any more.

I'm also using Cloudflare which I turned off for testing as well as I switched off caching in PyroCMS.

In the Chrome Developer Tools it shows the following issue:

[image: Console Error in Chrome Developer Tools]

The error relates to file /assets/cache/4e1ee6d64a845f2f82e18c6ed3f1423e.js:

```
this.complete=function(){loaded+=1;if(loaded===list.length){callBack(list);loaded=0;list=[];}};this.push=function(item){list.push(item);};this.getList=function(){return list;};},SequenceHandler=function(){var sequence=[];this.push=function(callBack){sequence.push(callBack);if(sequence.length===1){callBack();}};this.next=function(){sequence.shift();if(sequence.length){sequence[0]();}};};FileUpload=function(container){var fileUpload=this,uploadForm,fileInput,settings={namespace:defaultNamespace,uploadFormFilter:function(index){return true;},fileInputFilter:function(index){return true;},cssClass:defaultNamespace,dragDropSupport:true,dropZone:container,url:function(form){return form.attr('action');},method:function(form){return form.attr('method');},fieldName:function(input){return input.attr('name');},formData:function(form){return form.serializeArray();},requestHeaders:null,multipart:true,multiFileRequest:false,withCredentials:false,forceIframeUpload:false,sequentialUploads:false,maxChunkSize:null,maxFileReaderSize:50000000,replaceFileInput:true},documentListeners={},dropZoneListeners={},protocolRegExp=/^http(s)?:\/\
```

I don't think that some code is wrong because it worked earlier before for years but there is another reason - maybe related to Cloudflare, caching, php version, etc.

Does anyone have a clue what could be a solution?

Thanks,

Philip

Comment: What is that ending \ doing there

Comment: Hi Andrew, Thanks for your reply. Honestly I don't know. This code was marked as wrong: protocolRegExp=/^http(s)?:\/\. However I don't think that it is a code issue but something else related to PyroCMS / CKEditor, may it be settings, caching, etc.

Comment: I suggest your prettify your code so it's actually readable. Perhaps you're forgetting to close some blocks (due to he lack of closing braces)?

Comment: that regex is definitely invalid, not sure how it ended up in that condition. Is this code you wrote? It is very minified. You can take that regex and throw it in a pattern matcher ie: http://regexr.com/3f4bm and see that it is missing a `/` to close it.

Comment: Well, the full file is here: https://www.ailolabuenosaires.com/assets/cache/4e1ee6d64a845f2f82e18c6ed3f1423e.js Yes, it's minified and cached (probably by Codeigniter). I already emptied the cache to regenerate the file. Making changes in the file itself doesn't help because it will be overwritten.

Comment: I figured out how I can solve the issue: Setting Cloudflare to Developer Mode under Caching, emptying cache and reloading the page. Thereafter the file manager is working again. So, apparently there must be a conflict with Cloudflare which I couldn't fix.